# show and hide column with Ifelse in summary General

Tags: r

I am summary like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxs9H.png)

now i am trying to make my column show and hide , i want total_var = FALSE the summary should hide second column and if total_var = TRUE then it should show Total(second column) the summary will always have total column in second row.
i have tried ifelse but its not working
any solution....??

```
tt <- mtcars %>%
  tab_cols(total(), am %nest% vs) %>%
  tab_stat_cpct() %>%
  tab_pivot()

tt <- as.data.frame(tt)
total_var = FALSE
total_col <- ifelse(total_var== TRUE,1,0)
ifelse(total_col==1,tab1[,-2],tab1)
```

Comment: Please include all the packages that you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this worked now, i have used

```
total_col <- ifelse(total_var== TRUE,1,0)
if(total_col==0){tab2 = tab2[,!grepl("^#Tot",names(tab2))]}
```

now it worked for me , and able to hide and show Total column